# How is ground wire handled on 240V outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

I'm in the process of moving 240V outlet. The outlet has three wires connected.

See the image:
[image: outlet with 3 wires and ground missing]

In the junction box I can see the ground coming out of the outlet.
See the image:
[image]

So where is the ground wire inside the outlet? I'd like to know how this is handled.
Update: for some reason I didn't notice ground attached to the neutral. But it is there

[image]

Then I noticed a orange label and found the instruction:

[image]

So I wired the stove cord according to the code:

[image]

Measured all the connections with the voltmeter and all is now set up correctly. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: The grounding conductor may be clipped short, or attached outside of the enclosure. More concerning, is the gash in the insulation on the grounded (neutral) conductor (white wire).

Comment: so it is safe to just clip it short? I'm replacing the outlet and the wire so there won't be the gash in the insulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That outlet looks like a NEMA 10-20 or 10-50 and is an ungrounded outlet.  There are two 120V hot lines and one neutral.

This is an old outlet type and is no longer permitted in new installations.

Comment: well, how come I was able to buy the new NEMA 10-50 and it has the same design? I got this one http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-50-Amp-Thermoplastic-Power-Single-Outlet-Black-R50-05050-000/202066671

Comment: If you were just replacing an existing outlet, say because it cracked, then it would be allowed.  Also, stores can sell whatever they want, it's up to the installer to ensure it is allowed in the specific application.  What might be allowed in residential isn't allowed in commercial, etc.

Comment: @Grasper just because you can buy it doesn't mean its permitted.  Home improvement stores sell lots of crap that doesn't meet current building codes.

Comment: well, I have no way to use something else because the oven has the plug that fits only this type of outlet. Now you are going to tell me to replace the cable from the oven? Well, the house is old and if the inspector comes he can't tell me this is wrong because I can tell him, this is how it was done when I got the house.

Comment: at least now I know why Lowes didn't have it but Homedepot did.

Comment: Yes the solution is to replace the whip from the oven to use a 4 wire cable.

Comment: @Grasper if you told him "this is how it was done when I got the house", he would reply "but you're installing a new outlet location that was not here when you got the house".  Essentially anything as-is that was done to code at the time it was installed is grandfathered in, but anything new/changed needs to meet current code.

Comment: Also consider your insurance policy for your house.  If there's a fire, and they find out that you did something against code, they won't pay.

Comment: ok, do you have the link to what type of plug and outlet I need to use?

Comment: Probably NEMA 14-50

Answer (score 3):

NEMA 10-50 devices are ungrounded devices. They were commonly used before grounding systems were installed, and are no longer allowed by code in new installation.

Whoever installed this one, probably should have installed a grounded device instead. However, since they went with the ungrounded device, they likely cut off the grounding conductor from the cable.

If you're replacing this receptacle, you should install a new 4 wire cable, and new NEMA 14-50 device. This will also require you to install a new NEMA 14-50 cord on the stove.  Follow the manufacturer's documentation for the stove when replacing the cord, as it may require swapping around a bonding conductor in the stove.

Comment: so I did everything according to the code only one thing got me thinking. My old oven has only 3 connectors, black, red and white. My new 4 prong cord has 4. So I connected neutral(white) and ground(green) under one screw. I found this solution on YT. The oven doesn't have any ground screw attachment. Is this ok?

Comment: NO! That is not okay. Look up the manufacturer's documentation for the oven, or contact the manufacturer directly. There should be instructions on how to connect a grounding conductor to the oven.

Comment: What is the make and model of the oven?

Comment: it is kenmore  362 92212300

Comment: I updated my question with the proper result. Thanks for directions.

Comment: Glad you got it all hooked up properly.